# problems with apt-get install

Tags: apt

I've installed Ubuntu recently and I've been trying to install some programs using apt-get but it never seems to work, not even apt-get update works, here's what I get when I try to install something, in this case: java's jdk-7 using:

```
apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless
```

here's what I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-29 linux-headers-3.2.0-29-generic-pae
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
mkhas@mkhas-Inspiron-3520:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-29 linux-headers-3.2.0-29-generic-pae
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java icedtea-7-jre-jamvm java-common openjdk-7-jre-lib tzdata-java
Suggested packages:
  default-jre equivs sun-java6-fonts ttf-dejavu-extra fonts-ipafont-gothic
  fonts-ipafont-mincho ttf-telugu-fonts ttf-oriya-fonts ttf-kannada-fonts
  ttf-bengali-fonts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java icedtea-7-jre-jamvm java-common openjdk-7-jre-headless
  openjdk-7-jre-lib tzdata-java
 0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
 Need to get 44.1 MB of archives.
 After this operation, 63.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
 WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
   openjdk-7-jre-lib ca-certificates-java tzdata-java java-common openjdk-7-jre-         headless
  icedtea-7-jre-jamvm
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
0% [Connecting to lb.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.13)]
```

And it just get stuck at 0%

Edit: Yes, the internet is working fine on my system.

One thing I tried is changing the mirror server from which it's supposedly retrieving the packages from lb.archives.ubuntu.com to archives.ubuntu.com in /etc/apt/sources.list but it says that that file is read only and I can't make any changes to it.

I tried updating apt-get through

```
apt-get update
```

but I get this whenever I try to do that:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

EDIT: Issue resolved, I wasn't using sudo apt-get update and was only using apt-get update

Comment: is internet working on your system?

Comment: Are you using `sudo apt-get update` ?

Comment: For the moment, your initial `apt-get install` is still locking those files, do a `sudo ps ax | grep apt` and you should see the process that is locking those files. Try and `kill -TERM` the PID, if not, do a `kill -9`.. then run `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 0):

The `apt-get` command requires root privileges, so you need to run it with `sudo`. For example:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then you can install your packages:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless
```